# Reactjs: Callback for dangerouslySetInnerHTML complete

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently having a React Component like this:

```
        <div id="product-content" className="bz">
            <a className="anchor" id="content-anchor"></a>
            <h2 className="title-section">Thông tin sản phẩm</h2>
            <div className="fixed-menu-content">
                <div className="container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#content-anchor">Thông tin sản phẩm</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Video sản phẩm</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#rating-anchor">Đánh giá (19)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#guide-anchor">Hướng dẫn mua hàng</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: description}}></div>
        </div>
```

It seems that dangerouslySetInnerHTML doesn't impact to Component Lifecycle. I put this line in componentDidMount, but it return wrong result:

```
let b = $("#product-content").height(); // wrong: 600, true: 6500
```

If I try to run above line in console dev tool, it returns true result because component has been rendered completely.

How can I trigger callback for dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Comment: Could you add an onChange function for same element that has the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute?

Comment: It's not work, @EricL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a callback for completion of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` yet, you'll have to resort to [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified).

---

```
 // use ref to get the DOM Node
 <div 
   dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: description}}
   ref={myElement => this.myElement = myElement}
  >
 </div>

 // Listen for changes inside the DOM Node
 componentDidMount() { 
    this.myElement.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', () => {
      // execute your logic here...
    });
 }

 // Don't forget to clean up the listener
 componentWillUnmount() { 
    this.myElement.removeEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified');
 }
```

PS.

> Be very careful with this event (DOMSubtreeModified) it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler.

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified is only partially supported in IE 11 and therefore this will not work in IE 11

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) event has been deprecated in favor of the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

You could refactor the code proposed by lustoykov to use the new API:

```js
class ContentRenderer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      this.observer = new MutationObserver(this.handleMutation);
      this.observer.observe(this.myElement, {
        // Check config in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
        childList: true,
        attributes: true,
        characterData: true
      });
    }
  
    componentWillUnmount() { 
      this.observer.disconnect();
    }
    
    handleMutation() {
      console.log('mutation');
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <div 
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<div>Test</div>" }}
          ref={(myElement) => { this.myElement = myElement; }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```